# How to add a corner radius to a uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I noticed that in snapchat they rounded their corners of a uiviewcontroller. I was wondering how could I replicate the same thing accross all view controllers. Would I declare it in the app delegate or in each individual view controller. Could someone please show me how to do it. I have an example image below. Look in the top corners of the view controller and you'll see that there rounded. I'm trying to replicate that.

[image: example image]

Comment: You don't add a corner radius to a *UIViewController*, you add it to a *UIView's layer*. It may seem like a subtle thing, but you won't fully understand MVC until you know this.

Answer (score 14):

You could use an extension, then you could apply a corner radius on any view, including the view controller's view.  I haven't tried it though.

```
extension UIView {
    func makeCorner(withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.isOpaque = false
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myController.view.makeCorner(withRadius: 10.0)
```

Comment: `func roundCorners(with radius: CGFloat) { ... }`

Comment: How can I add this

Comment: What would go inside this function

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, hope it helps:

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, that's a pretty bad idea. I would suggest that you look at the [HIG documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/) when designing your UI.

That being said, to implement something like this, you can create a base class which would inherit from `UIViewController` where you would set `layer.cornerRadius` of the `view` property. Then you can have all your view controllers inherit from your base class. You can do this in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` in your base class